# PrintDialog with Landscape and Portrait pages

Tags: wpf, printing

I have a  *System.Window.Controls.PrintDialog* and I want to print pages with landscape mode and portrait mode in with single PrintTicket but it seems I only can set the orientation once.

As long as I want to print on paper this may not be a big deal but I want to print/create a PDF document from my Printjob. There I need pages with Landscape and Portrait mode in onc document.

So far I managed to rotate the landscape pages 90 degree and this works fine but in the PrintPreview it looks very strange because of the rotated content.

Comment: Did you ever find a way of doing this? I'd like to be able to do it for much the same reasons (printing to PDF with mixed portrait/landscape pages), and haven't figured out a way of getting it working.

Comment: Not an answer, but worked in a project where needed that also. After days of research I ended doing the same as you. However, an XPS document is capable of correct paper orientation (as seen when exporting from MS Word to XPS). Still waiting to see how is it done.

Answer (score 2):

A long time later ...

You can do this by providing an EventHandler that gets called, asking for a custom PrintTicket, before each page is printed. The PageViewModel here effectively comprises

```
PageViewModel{
    Page Page {get;set;}
    PageOrientation? PageOrientation {get;set}
}

if (PrintDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
  {
    XpsDocumentWriter xpsDocumentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(PrintDialog.PrintQueue);
    xpsDocumentWriter.WritingPrintTicketRequired += (s, e) =>
    {
      PageViewModel pVM = publicationVM.Pages[e.Sequence - 1];
      if (pVM.Orientation != null && pVM.Orientation != publicationVM.Orientation)
      {
        e.CurrentPrintTicket = new PrintTicket();
        e.CurrentPrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
      }
    };
    VisualsToXpsDocument visualsToXpsDocument = (VisualsToXpsDocument) xpsDocumentWriter.CreateVisualsCollator(PrintDialog.PrintTicket, PrintDialog.PrintTicket);
    visualsToXpsDocument.BeginBatchWrite();
    Page page;
    foreach (PageViewModel pVM in publicationVM.Pages)
    {
      page = pVM.Page;
      visualsToXpsDocument.Write(page);
    }
    visualsToXpsDocument.EndBatchWrite();
  }
```

and bingo! mixed Portrait and Landscape. Duplexing this is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Not as clean as you would like and more of a workaround but I think it might accomplish your goal.  You can use the [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) library to concatenate PDFs into one following multiple print jobs.  Here is some [sample code](http://blog.rubypdf.com/itextsharp/tutorial01/ap01Concat.cs.html).

Hopefully someone comes up with a more straight forward solution.